# Link html file to another html file

Tags: html

Say I have a webpage with multiple html documents

ex:

```
Homepage.html Aboutme.html Contactinfo.html
```

And at the bottom of all of these pages I want a little message

*"Hello and welcome to my website"*

But I want to change that later on to something else

*"I hope you enjoy my website"*

Can I have a separate Html document linked to my other html documents to easily change the code without having to go to each document

So like footer html will contain

```
<p>"Hello and welcome to my website"</p>
```

And it shows up on all my pages
then later I change it to

```
<p>"I hope you enjoy my website"</p>
```

and then it changes on all my pages

similar to how you can link css files but instead with code

Comment: Are you ok with using Javascript or PHP?

Comment: This can be done by using a pseudo element in CSS or even by using an iframe loading the footer. At least that would not require any client side javascript logic. But the _usual_ approach for such dynamic content is indeed using a server side language like `php` or similar.

Comment: I'm in an IT9 class pls I don't know anything

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with only HTML - it lacks that capability.

You can do this with PHP, it is called a server-side include, and looks like this. Each page would have, embedded amongst the HTML:

```
<p>Paragraph on this page</p>
<?php include 'inc/message.inc.php'; ?>
<p>Another paragraph of information</p>
```

*The above would load the contents of a file called message.inc.php and stored inside a folder called `inc`.*

Alternately, you can use jQuery (javascript):

```
$('.msg').load('inc/message.inc.php');
```

But first you would need to create an HTML tag with that classname *(note the link there - `.msg` with `class="msg"`)* `msg` could be a P tag, a div, a textarea, section, some kind of container.

```
<p class="msg"></p>
```

The PHP include is the better solution because the javascript will run after the DOM has been rendered, which *might* display a quick flash when the message is injected into the P element.

All that is required to use a PHP include is to use the `.php` file extension instead of `.html` -- that's it. If your webserver can do PHP (and most can), then it will instantly work.

*Note that using the `.php` extension will not cause any problems with the HTML/CSS/javascript -- all of that will continue to work as before. The only difference is that NOW it can also handle PHP.*

---

The file `message.inc.php` could simply be this:

**message.inc.php**

```
<p>Your cool message goes here</p>
```

That's it!